# incompatible types using Volley to get JSON in android

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-volley

I'm making an application and i'm using Volley to get the data from an API but in the `Request.Method.GET` it gives me an error that says "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String". Here u can see the method:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


/**
* A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
*/

public class NegociosFragment extends Fragment {

public RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

List<Empresas> empresas = rellenar();

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

 // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_negocios,container,false);
    //1. get a reference to recyclerView
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.reciclador);
    //2. set layoutManager
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    //3. create an adapter
    EmpresasAdapter adapter = new EmpresasAdapter(getActivity(), /*Empresas2.getEmpresas()*/empresas);
    //4. set adapter
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //5. set item animator to DefaultAnimator
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    return view;
}

private List<Empresas> rellenar() {

    final List<Empresas> empresas2 = null ;

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "my url of the API",
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");

                        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject objeto = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            int id = objeto.getInt("id");
                            String data1 = objeto.getString("data1");
                            String data2 = objeto.getString("data2");
                            String data3 = objeto.getString("data3");
                            String data4 = objeto.getString("data4");
                            String data5 = objeto.getString("data5");
                            String data6 = objeto.getString("data6");
                            String data7 = objeto.getString("data7");
                            String data8 = objeto.getString("data8");
                            String data9 = objeto.getString("data9");
                            Double double1 = objeto.getDouble("double1");
                            Double double2 = objeto.getDouble("double2");
                            String data10 = objeto.getString("data10");
                            String data11 = objeto.getString("data11");
                            String data12 = objeto.getString("data12");
                            String data13 = objeto.getString("data13");
                            String data14 = objeto.getString("data14");
                            String data15 = objeto.getString("data15");
                            String data16 = objeto.getString("data16");
                            String data17 = objeto.getString("data17");
                            String data18 = objeto.getString("data18");
                            String data19 = objeto.getString("data19");
                            String data20 = objeto.getString("data20");
                            String data21 = objeto.getString("data21");
                            String data22 = objeto.getString("data22");
                            String data23 = objeto.getString("data23");
                            String data24 = objeto.getString("data24");
                            String data25 = objeto.getString("data25");
                            String data26 = objeto.getString("data26");
                            String data27 = objeto.getString("data27");
                            //change null to default information
                            data1 = comprobarString(data1);
                            data2 = comprobarString(data2);
                            data3 = comprobarString(data3);
                            data4 = comprobarString(data4);
                            data5 = comprobarString(data5);
                            data6 = comprobarString(data6);
                            data7 = comprobarString(data7);
                            data8 = comprobarString(data8);
                            data9 = comprobarString(data9);
                            double1 = comprobarDouble(double1);
                            double2 = comprobarDouble(double2);
                            data10 = comprobarString(data10);
                            data11 = comprobarString(data11);
                            data12 = comprobarString(data12);
                            data13 = comprobarString(data13);
                            data14 = comprobarString(data14);
                            data15 = comprobarString(data15);
                            data16 = comprobarString(data16);
                            data17 = comprobarString(data17);
                            data18 = comprobarString(data18);
                            data19 = comprobarString(data19);
                            data20 = comprobarString(data20);
                            data21 = comprobarString(data21);
                            data22 = comprobarString(data22);
                            data23 = comprobarString(data23);
                            data24 = comprobarString(data24);
                            data25 = comprobarString(data25);
                            data26 = comprobarString(data26);
                            data27 = comprobarString(data27);




                            empresas2.add(new Empresas(id, data1, data2, data3,
                                    data4, data5, data6, data7,
                                    data8, data9, double1, double2, data10, data11,
                                    data12, data13, data14, data15, data16, data17, data18, data19,
                                    data20, data21, data22, data23, data24, data25, data26, data27));
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
      new Response.ErrorListener(){
          @Override
          public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){

          }
      }
    );
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    return empresas2;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

Double comprobarDouble(Double num){
    Double fin = null;
        if(num==null){
            fin=0D;
        }
        else if(num!=null){
            fin=num;
        }
    return fin;
}
String comprobarString(String txt){
    String text;
        if (txt==null){
            text="No disponible";
        }
        else if(txt.equals("null")){
            text="No disponible";
        }
        else{
            text=txt;
        }

    return text;
}





}
```

This is the constructor of Empresas:

```
public class Empresas {
int id;
String data1;
String data2;
String data3;
String data4;
String data5
String data6;
String data7;
String data8;
String data9;
Double double1;
Double double2;
String data10;
String data11;
String data12;
String data13;
String data14;
String data15;
String data16;
String data17;
String data18;
String data19;
String data20;
String data21;
String data22;
String data23;
String data24;
String data25;
String data26;
String data27;


public Empresas(int id, String data1,String data2,String data3,String data4,String data5,String data6, String data7,
                String data8, String data9, Double double1, Double double2, String data10, String data11, String data12, String data13,
                String data14, String data15, String data16, String data17, String data18, String data19, String data20, String data21, String data22,
                String data23, String data24, String data25, String data26, String data27){
    this.id=id;
    this.data1=data1;
    this.data2=data2;
    this.data3=data3;
    this.data4=data4;
    this.data5=data5;
    this.data6=data6;
    this.data7=data7;
    this.data8=data8;
    this.data9=data9;
    this.double1=latitud;
    this.double2=longitud;
    this.data10=data10;
    this.data11=data11;
    this.data12=data12;
    this.data13=data13;
    this.data14=data14;
    this.data15=data15;
    this.data16=data16;
    this.data17=data17;
    this.data18=data18;
    this.data19=data19;
    this.data20=data20;
    this.data21=data21;
    this.data22=data22;
    this.data23=data23;
    this.data24=data24;
    this.data25=data25;
    this.data26=data26;
    this.data27=data27;

}
}
```

This is the structure of the JSON

```
{
status: "OK",
code: 0,
message: "",
results: [
 {
 id: 42,
 data1: "data",
 data2: "data",
 data3: "data",
 data4: "data",
 data5: "data",
 data6: "data",
 data7: "data",
 data8: "data",
 data9: "data",
 double1: double1,
 double2: double2,
 data10: "data",
 data11: "data",
 data12: "data",
 data13: "data",
 data14: "data",
 data15: "data",
 data16: "data",
 data17: "data",
 data18: "data",
 data19: "data",
 data20: "data",
 data21: "data",
 data22: "data",
 data23: "data",
 data24: "data",
 data25: "data",
 data26: "data",
 data27: "data"
 },
```

The line where the error moves you at
[image: The line that the error marks]

Stacktrace
[image: Stacktrace]

This is the new Error: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post your model constructor?

Comment: the constructor from Empresas?

Comment: Yea  
the constructor from Empresas

Comment: @Nisarg there you have, i will post the structure of the JSON too

Comment: yea please post it

Comment: @Nisarg i'm sorry for taking so much time but is private data so i have to change it 1 by 1

Comment: try taking like objeto.getString("id"); it'll work

Comment: your json is invalid because `double1: double1` and also no `,` between items.

Comment: it keeps saying : error:incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String in the Request.Methos.GET

Comment: also, post your stacktrace.

Comment: there you have the images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "my url of the API",
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
```

To this:

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "my url of the API", null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
```

You're missing the parameter there.

Comment: i tried it and now it shows me a different error: String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Sorry, remove the cast to (String). Gonna edit the answer.

Comment: now i have an error in the JsonObjectRequest that says: Cannot resolve constructor'JsonObjectRequest(int,java.lang.String, null, anonymoues com.android.volley.Response.Listener<org.json.JSONObject>, anonymous com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener)'

Comment: Try to typecast `null` to `JSONObject` like `(JSONObject)null` there.

Comment: ok, now it doesnt give me an error there, but now i have a new error. I´ll post an image at the end of the question

Comment: Well bro, this is quite a new, and to me unknown error. Please accept the answer since it fixed your original problem. Google how to fix the new one, or post the new question. As from just reading the log, it needs more memory (for the emulator maybe?).

Comment: that´s right, you solved my question and i accept it :)